# Solving different voltage for I2C pull-up resistors

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, i2c, pullup, bus

I am designing my own PCB (based on the STM32F4). I am communicating with some devices using I2C.

The thing is that this devices are connected to the I2C bus, which uses two 4.7 kΩ resistors (pull-ups) to +3.3 V. Now, I am adding a new device and the datasheet specifies +1,8 V to I2C. The power supply for this element is +1,8 V-GND too. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Use  a bi directional level translator? Are you adding a second I2C slave 1.8V voltage to the master with 3.3V voltage?

Comment: I would change the 4.7K to 3.3K because of the added capacitance.

Comment: Could you explain more about your answer @Gil? Thanks!!

Comment: @AmitM I want to add a second slave, yes. At the end, I will have the master (Power supply to 3,3), one slave (power supply and pull ups to 3,3) and this new slave (power supply and pull ups to 1,8). I don't understand how to solve it.

Comment: You have to use a 3.3V to 1.8 V level translator.

Comment: If I change from 3,3 to 1,8 that's is good for power supply (I am using a LDO) but for the I2C bus, I have got two pull ups connected to 3,3 and I don't want to change that, where is supose to be connected the level translator? Just before the slave 2? (As if the slave were the level translator)

Comment: I like about 1 mA on the I2C lines when pulled to ground which the I2C chips do. They do not have the ability to source any current that comes from the pull ups. This allows a wired 'or' configuration on the bus. As you add wire, other ports, etc the capacitance of those lines increases. This slows down the rise time of the I2C signals thereby extending the signal out of tolerance potentially causing communication failure. You need pull up resistors on each I2C circuit, so if you go through a I2C Mux each channel needs pull up resistors to the appropriate voltage. Some modules may have pu res.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Check if your mysterious i2c chip tolerates 3.3v on SDA/SCL.
2. Check if your mysterious STM32F4 variant can understand a VIH (input high voltage) of 1.8v (which I don't think it can, considering the image below and a supply of 3.3v). The image is from a random STM32F4 device:

[image: STM32 IO characteristics]

According to image above, with a supply voltage of 3.3v, the minimum understandable "hi" level would be `0.7*3.3 = 2.1v`, way above 1.8v, so :

3. If it's possible, reduce the IO voltage of STM32 to a lower value
4. And finally, **use a level shifter.**

Comment: 1. No
3. By reducing power supply? 
4. How?
Thank you

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics Actually the level shifter solution (no. 4) is the best one if you can tolerate having a few more tiny components on your board. but if it's not possible, you can lower the power supply voltage (if it's fine by other components) so the MCU can understand 1.8v logic high value. The minimum voltage that is considered high, on the MCU, is `0.7 x Vcc`.

Comment: The I2C slave is this one (https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/0/8/e/2/3/AS7341_DS000504_3-00.pdf), see page 58 to see an I2C schematic example. But, in this little board, you can see they connected it to 3,3 V pull ups (https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/8/2/7/f/f/Qwiic_Spectral_Sensor_AS7341.pdf). I can't find that is possible in the datasheet or in the example in page 58.

Comment: I can't see how to use (and where) a level shifter. The I2C pull up resistors are connected to 3,3 and to the bus. All the slaves are connected to the bus, so where do I add the level shifter? As a slave (between the real slave and the bus) in the traditional I2C schematic?

Comment: If @"Developing Electronics" is willing to swap to an STM32L4, the original poster can use the VDDIO2 input to have an I2C bus on 1.8V